# Phonegap/Cordova FileSystem dirEntry.isDirectory generates error when should be simply false

Tags: javascript, cordova, filesystems

I am testing on Android and I have:

```
function initialize(){
    console.log('into initialize');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(e){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onSuccess, errorHandler);
}

function onSuccess(fs){
    fs.root.getFile('log.txt',{},function(fileEntry){console.log('the file is: ' + fileEntry.isFile);},errorHandler);
    fs.root.getDirectory('MyPictues',{},function(dirEntry){if(!dirEntry.isDirectory){console.log('My Pictures is not a directory');} else {console.log('My Pictures is a directory');}},errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };
  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
```

I call initialize() when document is loaded.
The strange thing is in the if on this line:

```
fs.root.getDirectory('MyPictues',{},function(dirEntry){if(!dirEntry.isDirectory){console.log('My Pictures is not a directory');} else {console.log('My Pictures is a directory');}},errorHandler);
```

I have inside my root a directory called "MyPictures", on the line above I misspelled it trying to verify if "MyPictues" exists but I get the 'NOT_FOUND_ERR' from the switches instead of simply getting the log: 'My Pictures is not a directory'.
If I do the test without misspelling the name I get right behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call initialize() function on document load, write

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

outside of function, after writing the onDeviceReady method will be called when device is ready
that time you will not get any error.
as

```
 <script>
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady(e){
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onSuccess, errorHandler);
}

function onSuccess(fs){
  fs.root.getFile('log.txt',{},function(fileEntry){console.log('the file is: ' +     fileEntry.isFile);},errorHandler);
  fs.root.getDirectory('MyPictues',{},function(dirEntry){if(!dirEntry.isDirectory){console.log('My Pictures is not a directory');} else {console.log('My Pictures is a directory');}},errorHandler);
 }

function errorHandler(e) {
 var msg = '';

switch (e.code) {
case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
  msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
  msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
  msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
  msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
  break;
case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
  msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
  break;
default:
  msg = 'Unknown Error';
  break;
 };
  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Did you test it? I tried with your code and I get the same error as well. However I see many times the  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false); inside a function executed on body loaded.